# Is there a way to use CSRF protection and JWT in a sails app together but not at the same time?

Tags: security, authentication, sails.js, jwt, csrf-protection

I'm working on an application using sails. web and mobile.

I want to use CSRF protection that sails provides when the app is visiting on the web. And if a request is send by the mobile app. send with the payload a jwt.

On the sails' documentation I found a property **csrf.routesDisabled** that disabled the CSRF for some routes. But that is not what I want. I'm trying to find a way to for example, check if the parameter jwt is send in the post request. And if the parameter was send then check and validate it. else, check for _csrf value of the form. Is this possible?

or the csrf protecction works before any information is send to the server?

my better choose is use jwt in the web app too?

any other good idea for solving this problem is welcome

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've built the web app with SailsJS and you're trying to reuse the controller actions as REST endpoints for external applications.

Really what you should do, is decouple the data access from the front-end. Have an isolated REST API - using token authentication - which is used by both a web front-end (and any other applications).

For example, I'm currently working with a SailsJS REST API, used by an EmberJS front-end and an iOS app. Both front ends login using user credentials, in order to receive an authentication token. This token is then used for any future requests. A policy locks down all but the login authentication endpoint, to validate the token

Comment: Thanks for your response @ScottFyfe that is what I'm trying to avoid, use token for web app too. 
restPrefix

Comment: I have a **restPrefix** in my sails app to separate blueprints from web views. 

And the only security I need is for post requests. basically everything else is absolutely public. 

So I'm thinking that if I enclose in a function all the code from for example the **update** event. and make another route to be used for the mobile app with its respective event in the controller. And depending form where the request comes check and validate in its respective event, for the web app use **_csrf** and **req.session.User.id**, and for mobile, token
After that, call the function to do the updates

Comment: Still sounds like a hacky workaround. You'll find it easier to maintain and scale, having the front-end being a separate entity from the REST API data access.